# "Sich befassen mit" vs. "sich beschäftigen mit"

Tags: difference, verb, verb-usage, verb-choice

> Ich **befasse** mich in letzter Zeit mit Deutsch lernen.
>
> Ich **beschäftige** mich in letzter Zeit mit Deutsch lernen.

Kann man diese Verben untereinander austauschen? Was ist der Unterschied?

Comment: Die "Warum"-Frage habe ich mal rausgenommen. Das ist nicht die Frage, die du stellen willst. – Unabhängig vom Verb finde ich den Satz nicht natürlich. Einfach: "In letzter Zeit lerne ich viel Deutsch."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interessant finde ich diesen Beispielsatz:

> Ich beschäftige mich am liebsten mit Musik.

Diese Sätze würde ich eher komisch finden:

> Ich befasse mich am liebsten mit Musik.
>   Ich befasse mich gerne mit Musik.

Weil „befassen“ schon beinhaltet, dass man etwas intensiv oder gerne tut. Geht es aber um einen Teilbereich oder speziellere Interessen, klingt „befassen“ oftmals gleichwertig oder besser, finde ich:

> Ich befasse mich mit klassischer Musik.

Um zum gegebenen Beispiel zurückzukehren, Folgendes, finde ich, klingt gut:

> In letzter Zeit beschäftige ich mich damit, Deutsch zu lernen.
>   Momentan befasse ich mich mit der deutschen Grammatik.

Answer (score 6):

Es gibt noch ein drittes Verb: **sich mit etwas *auseinandersetzen***. Prinzipiell sind sie austauschbar, jedoch *sich befassen* und *sich auseinandersetzen* implizieren, dass man sich mit etwas womöglich etwas intensiver *beschäftigt*.

Außerdem, hat das Wort *beschäftigen* einige Bedeutungen, die die anderen Verben **nicht** haben:

- **j-n beschäftigen** kann bedeuten: jemandem eine Beschäftigung geben (*»Kannst du bitte die Kinder solange beschäftigen, wenn ich telefoniere?«*), auch im Sinne von *anstellen* (*»Wir beschäftigen derzeit 100 Mitarbeiter«*), ebenso als *zu nachdenken geben* (*»Was beschäftigt dich gerade?«*)
- **beschäftigt sein** (im Englischen: *busy*) kann nicht durch eins der anderen Verben ersetzt werden.

Comment: "Auseinandersetzen" hat auch noch eine weitere Bedeutung, wo zu es dieses Wortspiel gibt: "Ich habe mich mit ihm auseinandergesetzt. Wir reden kein Wort mehr." (Ob das nun lustig ist, sei dahingestellt.)

Comment: @Em1 - Gute Bemerkung.

Answer (score 6):

Ich verwende "befassen" für eingehendere Beschäftigungen. Wie es scheint sieht es der Duden ähnlich, definiert er doch:

> sich [eingehend] beschäftigen, auseinandersetzen

Vielleicht hilft folgendes Beispiel:

> ich befasse mich in meiner Doktorarbeit mit ausgestorbenen Tierarten und beschäftige mich in meiner Freizeit mit der Erlernung des 
>   Deutschen.

Answer (score 5):

> Sich mit etwas **befassen**

bedeutet, dass sich mit einem Thema auseinandersetzt, dass man sich einstudiert.

> Sich mit etwas **beschäftigen**

bedeutet eher, dass man seine Zeit damit verbringt, etwas zu tun. Ob man dann auch tiefer ins Thema einsteigt, steht hier offen.

Answer (score 2):

sich befassen mit VS sich beschäftigen mit: der Unterschied im Gebrauch dieser zwei Verben sehe ich darin, dass man sie gezielt auf intellektuelle einerseits und praktische Interessen andererseits gebrauchen kann.

"Sich befassen mit" sehe ich eher auf einen intellektuellen Inhalt gerichtet. Mein Ausgangspunkt ist die Sinnverwandschaft zwischen "fassen" und "greifen". Aus dem Verb "greifen" leiten wir das Wort "Be-griff", was intellektuelle Bedeutung hat. Begriffe sind Bausteine unseres Verstandes. Also greifen - begreifen (intellektueller Vorgang des Verstehens); fassen - befassen (sich intellektuell mit etwas auseinandersetzen).

"Sich beschäftigen mit" ist eher im praktischen Sinne zu gebrauchen, immer dann wenn es um Resultate oder Lösungen geht.

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Ist das eine eigene Definition oder steht sie auch woanders? Falls sie auch woanders steht, bitte nach Möglichkeit verlinken und den relevanten Teil zitieren.